# Print all mach-o binaries which contain a specific string

Tags: command-line, bash

I am attempting to generate a list of every mach-o binary in the `/System` folder that contains the string "/Applications/".

I am comfortable excluding binaries which are not marked as executable (assuming any even exist), and I know how to retrieve a list of executable files in a folder:

```
find /System/ -type f -perm +111 -print
```

I also know how to retrieve the strings in a binary:

```
strings /path/to/executable
```

I can combine the two to retrieve a list of strings in every executable file in the `/System/` folder:

```
find /System/ -type f -perm +111 find -exec strings {} \;
```

And I can even `grep` the output, to find the exact string I'm looking for:

```
find /System/ -type f -perm +111 find -exec strings {} \; | grep /Applications/
```

Unfortunately, this isn't helpful. While `grep` will print any lines which contain my string, it won't actually show me what file that string came from. I can add the `-H` option, but because of how I'm feeding data to `grep` via `find`, all it shows is that the data comes from standard input.

I could tell `find` to print every executable file and then run `grep`, but that would result in too many lines of output. I only want to print those filenames where `grep` found something!

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: (And the _reason_ I want to do this is because https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214731/stop-finder-from-creating-aliases-when-moving-applications is still bothering me after all these years, god damnit! I want to try finding all the places this path is hardcoded, so I can investigate further and hopefully patch this once and for all.)

Comment: It seems that `grep` can find the string itself, so you don't really need `strings`.  I did a `grep '/Applications' /Applications/*/Contents/MacOS/*` and get things like: `Binary file /Applications/App Store.app/Contents/MacOS/App Store matches`. Not sure if that's exactly what you want.

Comment: OOOPS! Never mind... I reread the question and see that you want the executables under /System. Maybe this? `find /System -type f -perm +111 -exec grep /Applications "{}" ';'`  (and I would have edited the comment if I hadn't taken so long trying other things)

Comment: @aMike Thanks! It's hard to be sure without knowing the correct output, but I'm pretty sure using `grep` alone misses results that `strings` would find. If nothing else, it outputs far fewer files than I would expect.

Comment: `sudo find / -perm -4000`

Comment: Why not just use python? Trying to wrangle this into a shell one liner seems far more complicated than just calling into subprocesss. As a bonus, with python parallelization is easy rather than trying to wrangle gnu parallel into doing this